# Using Class.getResourcesAsStream to get Apache Commons Configuration

Tags: java, class, configuration, apache-commons

The ideal way to populate a `java.util.Properties` object seems to be by using some variation on

```
properties.load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourcesAsStream(String className));
```

The big idea being to point `Properties.load` at a InputStream of a class, rather than at a path.

How can this be done using `org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructors of the different containers (e.g. `org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration` and `org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLPropertiesConfiguration`) internally take care of this if you pass them a `String`. They internally use the API in `org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils` to try and find the resource in [the user home directory, the current classpath and the system classpath](https://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/ConfigurationUtils.html#locate%28java.lang.String%29).

Incidentally, you might find [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-06/01-qa-0606-load.html) useful when trying to figure out the "correct" class loader to use when loading properties files from the classpath.