# Apache Commons Configuration2 - multiple same name config files from classpath

Tags: java, configuration, apache-commons-config

What I am trying to do is the exact same thing as this question : [Using Class.getResourcesAsStream to get Apache Commons Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609588/using-class-getresourcesasstream-to-get-apache-commons-configuration) but using Apache Commons Configuration 2.

So far, I have tried to make a first maven project with test.properties like this in classpath :

```
test1=value1
```

Then, I made an other maven project with another test.properties like this in classpath :

```
test2=value2
```

In the second project, I put a dependency on the first one and I create a main in which I put :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configurations configurations = new Configurations();
    PropertiesConfiguration configuration = configurations.properties("test.properties");
    System.out.println(configuration.getString("test1"));

}
```

When I run the main, I want to get `value1` but I get `null`. Obviously the way I create the PropertiesConfiguration does not read the test.properties file present in the first module.

Any idea or suggestion to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do this by getting the URL with `getClassLoader().getResources("...")` and then iterating over those URL to load properties files and put them in a `CompositeConfiguration`.

Still, I wish Apache Commons Configuration2 handled this use case directly.

Maybe a prettier way exists ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configurations configurations = new Configurations();
    CompositeConfiguration compositeConfiguration = new CompositeConfiguration();

    Enumeration<URL> urls = ConfigurationTest2.class.getClassLoader().getResources("test.properties");
    while(urls.hasMoreElements()) {
        PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfiguration = configurations.properties(urls.nextElement());
        compositeConfiguration.addConfiguration(propertiesConfiguration);
    }
    System.out.println(compositeConfiguration.getString("test1"));

}
```

Comment: Are the multiple test.properties files in different packages?

Comment: No, this is the point. For this POC, I put both test.properties in `src/main/resources`